# How do I get web Api 2.0 to create bearer token using windows auth

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2, windows-authentication, asp.net-identity-2, bearer-token

I have the requirement that my MVC application use Mixed Auth meaning both Windows Auth and Basic Auth.   I have done this before but not with the new Identity model and Web API 2.0.  The Web API is hosted on the same domain.

I have the basic auth working with the Web API issuing a Bearer Token.   I am struggling with how I get the Windows Authentication working.  If possible I would want to use the same client side code regardless of the authentication so any ajax calls would just send the issued Bearer token.

Any advice on the best way to create a Bearer token when using Windows Authentication ?